Running out of memory processing excel files read from a directory
My script reads excel files that are uploaded overnight from a directory. For each file it opens the file, reads the data into a MYSQL table, then closes the file.
$dir ='';
$dh = '';
$file = '';
$cnt=1;

echo 'Start<br/><br/>';
//$dir = "public_html/system/matrix_test/"; //for automated running
$dir = "matrix_test/";
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    $n=0;
    $i=0;
    $x=0;
    
    echo 'open<br/>';
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        echo $file.' file 0<br/>';
        echo $cnt.' cnt 0<br/>';
        
        if($cnt<6) {
            require('includes/read_file_guts.php');
        
            
        } else {
            echo 'sleep-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
            sleep(30);
            require('includes/read_file_guts.php');
        } //sleep if    
        
                
    } //while file from dir loop
  }
}

I have php ini set for 256 but I am running out of memory. I have added a count and sleep set. If it just sleeps and continues I have the same problem regardless of the count number. If I have it skip a file when it sleeps it will work with a count up to 5. More than 5 I get the same problem. The out of memory error usually stops someplace on a phpexcel file. The read_file_gets.php included file is the phpexcel processing code. Any help is appreciated.

Sleeping won’t affect memory, unless maybe a GC happens to run I guess. The OOM is most likely in the read guts file. If this were me, I’d run one file per process, that way PHP gets a fresh start each time. You can have a single master PHP process if you want still that forks new processes.

Assuming that the files are of similar size and complexity, if you double the memory do you get twice as many loops before it runs out of memory?
You mention closing the file, but not how the database connections are managed. Are they also being closed and reopened each loop?

Without knowing the contents of read_file_guts we cannot really help

If find it strange to include the same file over and over again in the loop. That's not the usual practice.

How big are the Excel files?
